# Looping through cursor and passing record to procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm parsing through xml and i need to update table record in autonomous transaction. For this i need to pass cursor record to procedure, how can i do that? f.e.

```
procedure process_message(
  p_xml in xmlType) is
  cursor c_parse_xml(cp_xml in xmltype) is
    select
      column_name_1,
      ...,
      column_name_n
    from
      xmltable(
        ...);
begin
  for r_rec in c_parse_xml(p_xml) loop
    update_table_records(r_rec);
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: What does your XML contain? Column names, table names, values? And what should you do for every row extracted from the cursor? Here you find something on [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a package.  Declare cursor type as package-level cursor.  Then you 
can reference cursor record with %ROWTYPE as parameter to another procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE MyPackage
IS
  CURSOR c_parse_xml
  IS
    SELECT 'A' c1, 1 c2 FROM dual;
  PROCEDURE proc1;
  PROCEDURE update_table_records(
      P_Rec IN c_parse_xml%ROWTYPE );
END MyPackage;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE body MyPackage
IS
  PROCEDURE proc1
  IS
  BEGIN
    FOR c_rec IN c_parse_xml
    LOOP
      update_table_records( c_rec );
    END LOOP;
  END proc1;
  PROCEDURE update_table_records(
      P_Rec IN c_parse_xml%ROWTYPE )
  IS
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
  BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line(P_Rec.c1 || ' ' || P_rec.c2 );
  END update_table_records;
END MyPackage;
```

Comment: (note simplified cursor definition, etc as example.)

Comment: I personally would move that cursor definition from the spec to the body (i.e. private global, not public global); there doesn't seem to be a need to expose it to the entire world, at least in your example.

Comment: Yes, you can move cursor and update proc  to package body.  Was just quick-and-dirty attempt.  Thanks.